# How to fit text labels on Seaborn log-log scatterplots?

Tags: python, plot, seaborn, scatter-plot, loglog

My question is how to adjust a Seaborn log-log scatterplot to fit text labels? MWE:

```
mport seaborn as sns
mport seaborn.objects as so
f = sns.load_dataset("penguins").sample(frac = 0.1)
f['island'] = 'long names here'
 Arbitrary tweak distributions
f['bill_length_mm'] = df['bill_length_mm'].apply(lambda x: 2.0**(x / 5))
f['bill_depth_mm'] = df['bill_depth_mm'].apply(lambda x: 2.0**((x - 10) / 2))
(
   so.Plot(df, x='bill_length_mm', y='bill_depth_mm', text = 'island')
   .add(so.Dot()).add(so.Text(valign='bottom'))
   .scale(x = 'log', y = 'log')
   .save('test.png')
)
```

[image]

As you can see on the resulting image, the labels get cropped by the edges. This
would be relatively easy to fix if I were using linear axes. But how
to do it when drawing logarithmic scatter plots?

Comment: Increase the xmargin through `Plot.theme`?

Comment: Due to the logarithmic scales I found that to be difficult.

Comment: Margins are expressed in fractions of the axes size, the scale doesn't matter.